# PayPal API returns RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND / INVALID_RESOURCE_ID but the transaction is listed in the Sandbox Business account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a similar issue.

**Setup**

- PayPal Sandbox environment
- Two test accounts (Personal and Business account). During the tests the personal account buys a product. The transaction goes to the Business account.
- I created REST API app which is connected to the Sandbox Business account above.
- I logged in to: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ with the credentials of the Business account to generate a PayPal button. The HTML code of the button is added to my website.

**Steps**

- I open the website and click the PayPal button.
- I log into PayPal Sandbox with the credentials of the Personal account.
- I complete the payment process.
- I log into the Business account and I see that the transaction (order) is listed there. I can see the Transaction ID.

**Issue**

In all requests to the API I use the Client ID and the Secret of the REST API app which I already created for the purposes of the tests.

After that I opened Postman and I sent the following request to PayPal API to generate an access token (Doc: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/).

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

So far, so good. Then I send an API request to PayPal APIv1 to get more details about the order. I use the Transaction Id which according to what I read is identical to Order ID.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/TRANSACTION_ID \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

and I get this:

```
{
    "http_code": 404,
    "body": {
        "name": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
        "message": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
        "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
        "debug_id": "c02871817abba"
    }
}
```

I tried APIv2:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/ORDER_ID \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

and I get this:

```
{
    "http_code": 404,
    "body": {
        "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
        "details": [
            {
                "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
                "description": "Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again."
            }
        ],
        "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
        "debug_id": "c2c24f91a44fd",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
                "rel": "information_link",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Confusion**

The transaction is clearly listed in the Business account but the API says that there no such transaction.

Suggestions/Solutions?

---

**Solution**

The default behaviour of the payments initiated via PayPal button (generated with the Business account) is *Sale* but not *Order*. For more details about the differences between the two, read here - https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-differences-between-the-express-checkout-payment-actions-ts1501

The solution is to make a request to another PayPal API method (check: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-plus/germany/how-to/show-sale/?fbclid=IwAR30yROZMjKT2LlRgSRuVBMGrjdmN1MGbuJ50rUiUBWwW11FSpGdxk5JNpY#show-sale-details)

Here is the request returning correct data.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/TRANSACTION_ID \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

The default behaviour of the payments initiated via PayPal button (generated with the Business account) is Sale but not Order. For more details about the differences between the two, read [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-differences-between-the-express-checkout-payment-actions-ts1501).

The solution is to make a request to another PayPal API method check [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-plus/germany/how-to/show-sale/?fbclid=IwAR30yROZMjKT2LlRgSRuVBMGrjdmN1MGbuJ50rUiUBWwW11FSpGdxk5JNpY#show-sale-details)

Here is the request returning correct data.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/TRANSACTION_ID \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

Answer (score 0):

v2/orders objects are for payment approval only, they are not transactions. Their IDs should only be persisted about a month for debugging purposes, as they serve no accounting purpose and are not referenceable in PayPal.com

A PayPal transaction on the other hand is represented by a v2/payments object, returned when you capture a v2/order. You can get a capture's details again with the appropriate GET call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get